# Работа с XML,при помощи JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Есть такой XML

```
<apartment>
        <area total="67.60" heating="65.00"/>
</apartment>
```

Незнаю как мне правильно указать total и heating.
Для Area нужно создавать отдельный класс? Или можно как то иначе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё очень просто. [Здесь](http://www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/System_Xml_Schema/BuildSchema/BuildXMLSchema.aspx) можно сгенерить XSD по вашему XML. Затем выполняем команду `xjc ваш_файл.xsd` в результате чего получите два файла Appartment.java и ObjectFactory.java

**Appartment.java**

```
// Этот файл создан с помощью архитектура JavaTM для реализации примера XML Binding(JAXB), v2.2.8-b130911.1802 
//  См. http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb 
// Любые изменения этого файла будут потеряны 
// после повторной компиляции исходной схемы. 
// Время создания: гггг.ММ.дд в чч:мм:сс PM MSK 
//


package generated;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * Класс Java для anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * В следующем фрагменте схемы указано ожидаемое содержимое данного класса.
 * 
 * 
 * <complexType>
 *   <complexContent>
 *     <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       <sequence>
 *         <element name="area">
 *           <complexType>
 *             <complexContent>
 *               <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 <attribute name="total" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal" />
 *                 <attribute name="heating" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal" />
 *               </restriction>
 *             </complexContent>
 *           </complexType>
 *         </element>
 *       </sequence>
 *     </restriction>
 *   </complexContent>
 * </complexType>
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "area"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "apartment")
public class Apartment {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Apartment.Area area;

    /**
     * Получает значение свойства area.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Apartment.Area }
     *     
     */
    public Apartment.Area getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    /**
     * Задает значение свойства area.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Apartment.Area }
     *     
     */
    public void setArea(Apartment.Area value) {
        this.area = value;
    }


    /**
     * Класс Java для anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * В следующем фрагменте схемы указано ожидаемое содержимое данного класса.
     * 
     * 
     * <complexType>
     *   <complexContent>
     *     <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       <attribute name="total" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal" />
     *       <attribute name="heating" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal" />
     *     </restriction>
     *   </complexContent>
     * </complexType>
     * 
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "")
    public static class Area {

        @XmlAttribute(name = "total")
        protected BigDecimal total;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "heating")
        protected BigDecimal heating;

        /**
         * Получает значение свойства total.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link BigDecimal }
         *     
         */
        public BigDecimal getTotal() {
            return total;
        }

        /**
         * Задает значение свойства total.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link BigDecimal }
         *     
         */
        public void setTotal(BigDecimal value) {
            this.total = value;
        }

        /**
         * Получает значение свойства heating.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link BigDecimal }
         *     
         */
        public BigDecimal getHeating() {
            return heating;
        }

        /**
         * Задает значение свойства heating.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link BigDecimal }
         *     
         */
        public void setHeating(BigDecimal value) {
            this.heating = value;
        }

    }

}
```

**ObjectFactory.java**

```
// Этот файл создан с помощью архитектура JavaTM для реализации примера XML Binding(JAXB), v2.2.8-b130911.1802 
//  См. http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb 
// Любые изменения этого файла будут потеряны после повторной компиляции исходной схемы. 
// Время создания: гггг.ММ.дд в чч:мм:сс PM MSK 
//


package generated;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the generated package. 
 * An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create 
     * new instances of schema derived classes for package: generated
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Apartment }
     * 
     */
    public Apartment createApartment() {
        return new Apartment();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Apartment.Area }
     * 
     */
    public Apartment.Area createApartmentArea() {
        return new Apartment.Area();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего придется делать два класса: первый будет @XmlRootObject и будет содержать ссылку на второй, где будет указано total и heating